# eliminating an addition sign from a calculator

Tags: javascript, calculator

Can I delete an addition sign in a input field after it has been calculated.

Example:  `input_A: (15*2)+30....` Than after it is calculated the Input_A field looks like this : `(15*2),30.`

Check it out:-

http://jsfiddle.net/qvDFY/12/

Comment: JS has quite a few [string methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Methods_unrelated_to_HTML) that can help with this sort of thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can, using the [`.replace`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp) function.

And [here](http://jsfiddle.net/qvDFY/13/)'s an example.

Comment: He is taking about javascript???

Comment: Yes, he's talking about javascript

Comment: After edited your anser is correct..

Comment: thank you very much Gareth, one question though. When I have two addition signs it will only eliminate the first. Example 15+2+3... becomes 15,2+3

Comment: Ah, sorry, change replace("+", ","); to replace(/\+/g, ",");